# Convert every Item of a list to string in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, listboxitem, converters

The problem seems simple, but i cant´t manage it. I have a list from ListBox in WPF and i want to read every items of this list and test it, if it is already existing in this list. Therefore i try to convert the ListItem to an string in a foreach costruction. But it seems, that lbi is null and i have no idea why. This is my Code:

```
foreach(object lbi in liste.Items)
{
     ListBoxItem something = (ListBoxItem)liste.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lbi);
     if (something.Content.ToString() != "someotherString")
          liste.Items.Add(something.Content.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the objects that were added to the ListBox?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove duplicates from the ListBox?

Comment: The type in a ListBox is usually untyped :) That is the reason for the attribute object lbi for the method ContainerFromItem().

Comment: I dont´t want to remove duplicates from a list, i want to avoid duplicates in list by testing for a duplicate before i add the someotherString to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.Cast<string>()`:

```
var filtered = liste.Items.Cast<string>().Where(x=> x!= "someotherString");
liste.Items.Clear();
liste.Items.AddRange(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanx for the quick respnse, but this doesn´t match in my case. I neew to test a new string before i add it to the list. This idea is quiet good but doen´t fix my problem. The bis question is: Why is the object lbi = NULL in my Code (this is, what my Debugger tells me).

Comment: well this checks with the string `someotherString` before adding it to the list

Comment: and about your question, maybe you have entered some null values to the list

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand this code. If i always collapse the existing list and add a new item after that, i will always will have only one item in the list. And i am using ItemCollection. AddRange is not included there.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates in a ListBox...

```
    private void OpCode()
    {
        var result = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().GroupBy(test => test)
               .Select(grp => grp.First())
               .ToArray();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(result);
    }
```

**EDIT**

To check as you are adding...

```
    private void AddItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       AddToListBox(InputText.Text);
    }

    private void AddToListBox(string newItem)
    {
        if (Names.Items.Contains(newItem))
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry that item is already in the listbox.");
        else
            Names.Items.Add(newItem);
    }
```

Comment: Thanx, but the challange is not to remove duplicates. It is to avoid duplicates by testing befor add them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with checking for duplicates before you add new items is that it doesn't scale very well. Generally speaking, the order of execution will be O(n^2), which will be fine for a small number of items but will grow exponentially.

A better way to handle this is to maintain a separate `HashSet<string>` containing all the strings that have already been added to the list, and to then check this before adding any new ones. Hash table lookups occur in constant time (for all intents and purposes), thus reducing the order of execution to O(n).

Hash table insertions also occur in constant time, so this can also be used to quickly test for duplicates within an already-existing list, or for determining which elements in set S already exist in set T; you simply start by creating a HashSet for the list you already have.